# Cannot attach to geth node running inside container

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc, docker

I am trying to run a node inside a docker container.

I am able to run a geth node locally, and attach it via IPC with these simple commands:

`geth --fast --cache=512`
Then
`geth attach`, it works fine.

Then I run a docker container (`ethereum/client-go`) with the same parameter, volume mounted on same ethereum folder.

Docker command:

`docker run -d --name ethereum-node -v /Users/****/Library/Ethereum:/root/.ethereum -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go --fast --cache=512`

The geth.ipc file is present, but I cannot attach.

`$ geth attach
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /Users/****/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused`

I tried to read/write geth.ipc:

- When geth is run locally:

  `$ cat geth.ipc
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}`
- When under container :

  `$ cat geth.ipc
  cat: geth.ipc: Connection refused`

Running OSX 10.12.1, docker 1.12.3

Answer (score 1):

```
$ docker exec -it ethereum-node /geth attach ipc://root/.ethereum/devchain/geth.ipc
```

Try to use this command if it works. Maybe you should change geth.ipc path in the command.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try

`geth attach http://localhost:8545`

The default geth console connectivity is via IPC which requires access to geth.ipc file handler.